# Elasticsearch date query. People who were born in a certain month

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have a field with the following mapping:

```
birthdate: { type: :date, format: :dateOptionalTime }
```

1. I need to find everyone who were born in month of May (including all years)
2. Another query is to find all people who were born on 'August 25' (including all years)

What would be the query for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html)

All people born in May of any year:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.birthdate.date.monthOfYear == 5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All people born on August 25th (any year)

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.birthdate.date.monthOfYear == 8 && doc.birthdate.date.dayOfMonth == 25"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do we have another options for today? @Val

Answer (score 3):

Just for the archives, ES 7 brought some braking changes https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_getdate_and_getdates_removed

It is now:

```
POST /people/_search?size=50
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
       "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": "doc['jour'].value.getMonthValue() == 5",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-datetime.html#_datetime_pieces_examples

Answer (score 0):

```
GET index_name/doc_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc.field_name.date.getMonthOfYear() == month_number",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is different from the accepted answer? Thanks.

Comment: filtered doesn't support in the newest version

Answer (score -2):

First question:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "birthdate": {
                  "gte": "2015-05-01",
                  "lt": "2015-06-01"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Second question:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "birthdate": {
                  "gte": "2015-08-25",
                  "lte": "2015-08-25"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/36c800cabbe4143ecf72144d02e58e267c1e761a

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was probably not specific enough. I need to get results for ALL years, not only for 2015

Comment: Yeah, that's a very different question.