# Elasticsearch is giving unnecessary records on match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get All the documents whose dateofbirth is having substring "-11-09".

This is my elasticsearch query :

```
{ "query": { "bool" : { "must": { "match": { "dobdata": ".*-11-09.*"} } } } }
```

And the result i am getting is

```
{
 "took": 8,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
  "total": 4,
  "max_score": 5.0782137,
  "hits": [
   {
     "_index": "userindexv1",
     "_type": "usertype",
     "_id": "58f9a9d1acf8c47037000038",
     "_score": 5.0782137,
     "_source": {
      "fullname": "Eshwar ",
      "fullname_raw": "Eshwar ",
      "mobile1": "7222222256",
      "uid": "UIDS1010",
      "mobile2": "",
      "classname": "Class 5",
      "classname_raw": "Class 5",
      "divid": 63,
      "category": "S",
      "dobdata": "2010-11-09"
     }
   },
   {
    "_index": "userindexv1",
    "_type": "usertype",
    "_id": "57960b35acf8c4c43000002c",
    "_score": 1.259227,
    "_source": {
     "fullname": "Sindhu ",
     "fullname_raw": "Sindhu ",
     "mobile1": "9467952335",
     "uid": "UIDS1006",
     "mobile2": "",
     "classname": "class 1s Group for class g",
     "classname_raw": "class 1s Group for class g",
     "divid": 63,
     "category": "S",
     "dobdata": "2012-11-08"
    }
   },
   {
    "_index": "userindexv1",
    "_type": "usertype",
    "_id": "58eb62d2acf8c4d43300002f",
    "_score": 1.1471639,
    "_source": {
     "fullname": "Himanshu ",
     "fullname_raw": "Himanshu ",
     "mobile1": "9898785484",
     "uid": "",
     "mobile2": "",
     "classname": "Play Group",
     "classname_raw": "Play Group",
     "divid": 63,
     "category": "S",
     "dobdata": "2012-11-08"
    }
   },
   {
    "_index": "userindexv1",
    "_type": "usertype",
    "_id": "580dbe5bacf8c4b82300002a",
    "_score": 1.1471639,
    "_source": {
     "fullname": "Sai Bhargav ",
     "fullname_raw": "Sai Bhargav ",
     "mobile1": "9739477159",
     "uid": "",
     "mobile2": "7396226318",
     "classname": "class 1s Group for class g",
     "classname_raw": "class 1s Group for class g",
     "divid": 63,
     "category": "S",
     "dobdata": "2012-11-07"
    }
   }
 ]
}}
```

I am getting the records whose dateofbirth does not contain the string "-11-09". I tried to work around it. I am not able to find the soultion.

I am new to elasticsearch. I want only the first record. Can anyone please help me out. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: What kind of type is the the field dobdata? it seems to be a date datatype. Your query is for text datatype. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640437/elasticsearch-date-query-people-who-were-born-in-a-certain-month

Comment: also take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626212/elasticsearch-how-to-query-a-date-field-using-a-month-date-range-filter

Comment: it is string datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I faced same problem and I solved it by doing two things.
1. Changed the format of date of birth from Y-m-d to YMd and made the index as not_analyzed.
2. Used wildcard query insteadof match query

```
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
       "dobdata": {
          "value": "*Nov09*"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

It solved my problem.Hope this will solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

For getting results with month-date=11-09 use following query.
The mapping for dobdata is

```
"dobdata": {
        "type": "text",

        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

Query is:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/userindexv1/_search" -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "dobdata.keyword":"*-11-09*"
    }
  }
}'
```

Also use multifield mapping instead of _raw fields Refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).

Answer (score 0):

@K Sathish so you use elasticsearch 2.x? String type for date is not so confortable. I suggest to you to change the datatype from string  in date type , so you can get also the range query. Once changed in date type you can make your query in elastic 2.x in this way:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.dobdata.date.monthOfYear == 11 && doc.dobdata.date.dayOfMonth == 9"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```